# Django REST: Can't get url to work with APIView "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to add a function which deletes every course with a certain category id (cat_id).

My usage would be as follows:

```
http://....:8000/course-delete/?cat_id=9
```

This was my idea, but I'm getting the following error:

```
"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
```

**url**

```
path('course-delete/', CourseDelete.as_view(), name='test')
```

**view**

```
class CourseDelete(APIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()

    def delete(self, request):
        cat_id = request.query_params['cat_id']
        queryset = Course.objects.filter(category=cat_id)
        queryset.delete()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My call from axios (ReactJS)

```
  axios
    .delete("http://localhost:8000/ctg-delete/", {
      params: {
        cat_id: cat_id
      }
    })
```

Comment: Well, you did only implement `delete`. What do you expect a `get` to do?

Comment: @DeepSpace This should be a delete function only. I'm calling it from my ReactJS application as a delete request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the backend is receiving a get request then there must be something wrong with your axios call (I assume that the url part in the call `url/ctg-delete/` is only for the demo purpose since it's not a valid variable name nor quoted and does not match to the url pattern defined in django). Try to post a little more frontend code, could be a typo before the axios call. Also remember to check if `cat_id` exist in the params before accessing it in the view to prevent server errors in production.

Comment: @Foocli It was just a place holder for the actual url, I thought that was obvious. Fixed it. cat_id is coming through.. I have no clue why it's coming through as a GET request instead of DELETE..